# Django-form : security problems

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two views : myview and a view-2.

view-two loads two values (manie and pablo) and send it to the template :

```
def view-two(request):
    manie = ObjectUno.objects.all().count()
    pablo = ObjectDos.objects.all().count()
    ...
    return render(request,"website/maniePablo.html",locals())
```

In maniePablo.html, I implement a process for send these two values to other view named "myview" :

```
<form hidden method="POST" action="{% url 'myview' %}" id="myform">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input value="{{pablo}}" name="pablo">
    <input value="{{manie}}" name="manie">
</form>
<a onclick="$('#myform').submit();" id="BTNmesp" class="btn btn-success" role="button"> XXX </a>
```

On click on btn XXX, my view "myview" get these two values like this :

```
def myview(request) : 
    ...
    if "pablo" in request.POST :
        nbpablo = request.POST["pablo"]
        nbmanie = request.POST["manie"]
    ...
```

With this process : 
- I can send values to my view and not displayed these values in url (example : localhost:8000/nameofurl/manie/pablo...).
- myview not loads also these values like view-two (Power saving)

**But I want to know if this process is good and if he can caused security problems ?**

*If isn't a good solution, I will used ajax...*

Comment: You should update your question to expand upon your comment on Daniel's answer. This (to me) seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question and I explained my problem.

Comment: Why does `view-two` need to be a view at all? It looks like it can just be a method that can be called by your other view that returns whatever data values you want it to, otherwise if its just those 2 counts, why not just do those 2 counts inside the other view as well?

Comment: I don't understand everything but view-two render to "maniePablo.html" and myview to other page (other template). In the template of myview, I need displayed these two values (displayed also in maniePablo.html).

Comment: So why not just query the database in the other view too?

Comment: Because I think, the page load time increases...

Comment: I can guarantee that the load time would be a lot less than the time it would take to call an ajax or post request and retrieve the values a second time. Of course you can remove the `.all()` since this resolves the query with all of the objects when really you just need `ObjectUno.objects.count()`.

Comment: Ah ! how do you know that the process with ajax take more time than  ObjectUno.objects.count() ?

Comment: Because `count` is almost instant for a start, even if it wasn't an ajax request would have to send a request, handle the request, go through any middleware and authentication you have, return the request, at which point your javascript would then have to parse the returned data and then display them to the page. And even without this, You have already had to call a second page first to actually get this data which means to get this data on this page you first need to call the first view anyway which does the one call you're trying to avoid

Comment: Thank you very much, I will  query the database in the other view ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unless you’re planning to build Web sites and applications that do nothing but publish content, and don’t accept input from your visitors, you’re going to need to understand and use forms.

Django provides a range of tools and libraries to help you build forms to accept input from site visitors, and then process and respond to the input.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#more-about-django-form-classes

And Validators
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: My problem is that I want my template send informations to myview and I want these informations are not displayed in the url. (Sadly in Django, the attributes of view must be displayed in the url...)

Comment: If you already can generate this information at backend side, you not need add this info to post form. You only adding csrf token for be sure it is really right person.

Answer (score 0):

This is not in any way secure. Anyone can see those values by looking at the page source, and change them via the developer tools in the browser before submitting.

I would question why you need to provide them at all. They are coming from the server in the first place, and you're posting them straight back; what's the point? You could more easily get them directly on the server in the code that handles the post.

Comment: I have two views : myview and a view-2. view-2 loads the values {{pablo|length}} and {{manie|length}}. But myview need also these values but I don't want she loads also. So myview get these values (loaded by view-2). Finally view-2 send two values to myview via my template.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question for understand better my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A short Answer: use django session if don't want that informations are displayed in the url and in backend check if value is the same in request.session

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/